# is my eventListener out of scope?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i am currently creating a shooting game , currently i have a main class which is the place where i add "main childs" at, and  i have a object class "gunner", i added that "gunner" to my main, and i have a eventListener,MOUSE_CLICK on the gunner class, however when i did a click nothing happens, why is that so? in my case the gunner is supposed to shoot bullets. is the event not being dispatched to my gunner object?

constructor of my main class.

```
    public function waterMain() 
    {
        Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
        canPlay = true;
        soundTimer = new Timer(300, 1);
        soundTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, waterSoundHandler, false, 0, true);
        waterMovementSound = new pondSound();
        bg = new Background(stage);
        myRippler = new Rippler(bg , 20, 5, 5);
        //event listeners
        addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin);
        addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, onTouchBegin);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMoveTriggered);

        addChild(bg);
        touchPoints = Multitouch.maxTouchPoints;
        if (Multitouch.supportsGestureEvents && Multitouch.supportsTouchEvents)
        {
            trace("Multitouch gesture supported");
            var inputField:TextField = new TextField();
            inputField.border = true;
            inputField.wordWrap = true;
            inputField.text = "Multitouch gesture,touch supported,MTP : "+touchPoints;
            addChild(inputField);
        }else if (Multitouch.supportsTouchEvents)
        {
            trace("touch  supported");
            var inputField2:TextField = new TextField();
            inputField2.border = true;
            inputField2.wordWrap = true;
            inputField2.text = "Multitouch touch supported,MTP : "+touchPoints;
            addChild(inputField2);
        }
        //game
        //creating gunner
        var gun:gunner = new gunner(stage);
        gun.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        gun.y = stage.stageHeight;
        addChild(gun);
    }
```

gunner class

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author ...
     */
    public class gunner extends MovieClip
    {
        private var _stageRef:Stage;
        public function gunner(stageRef:Stage) 
        {
            _stageRef = stageRef;
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rotateTurret);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fireBullet);
        }


        private function rotateTurret(evt:Event):void 
        {
            //calculations, distance, angle etc
            var a:Number = _stageRef.mouseX - this.x;
            var b:Number = _stageRef.mouseY - this.y;
            var angRad:Number = Math.atan2(b, a);
            var angDeg:Number = (angRad * 180 / Math.PI);

            rotation = angDeg;
        }
        private function fireBullet(mouseEvt:MouseEvent):void
        {

            _stageRef.addChild(new bullet(_stageRef, 500,500));
        }
    }

}
```

bullet class

```
public class bullet extends MovieClip
{
    //variables
    private var _bulletSpeedVector:Point;
    private var _stageRef:Stage;
    private var _maxX:Number = 1024;
    private var _maxY:Number = 768;
    public function bullet(stageRef:Stage,x:Number,y:Number) 
    {
        _stageRef = stageRef;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);
    }
    private function loop(e:Event) : void
    {
        //move bullet

        /*if (this.x > _maxX || this.x < 0)
            removeSelf();
            else if (this.y > _maxY || this.y < 0)
            removeSelf();
            */
    }
    private function removeSelf() : void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

        if (_stageRef.contains(this))
            _stageRef.removeChild(this);
    }


}
```

Comment: Not the answer for your main problem, but use class names capitalized ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure why this happens, but when i changed it to MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, it works. but with click it cant work.

Comment: and yes i have changed my class first letter name to capital ;)

Comment: Can you put trace("onTouchBegin") in onTouchBegin and trace("fireBullet") in fireBullet functions, and try mouse click. Maybe your touch event overrides mouse click event.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, you MouseEvent.Click will only register if you click the gunner and not the main stage.  Instead of adding the EventListener on the gunner, you may want to register your EventListener on the stage instead.  Try replacing :

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fireBullet);
```

in your gunner's constructor by :

```
_stageRef.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fireBullet);
```

This way, fireBullet should be called everytime you click on the stage. If I am right, clicking on your gunner right now will make him shoot a bullet.

Comment: hi, i tried this, i need to be clicking my turret for it to shoot bullets .

Comment: Assuming your waterMain is a MovieClip, pass it's "this" to the Gunner's constructor and register the EventListeners to it instead.

New Constructor would look like :
    public function gunner(stageRef : Stage, mainMC : MovieClip) 
    {
        _stageRef = stageRef;
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rotateTurret);
        mainMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fireBullet);
    }

If waterMain isn't the "main MovieClip" of your program, find the MovieClip that is and pass it to Gunner so that he can register his EventListener to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fireBullet);
```

and the first name of the class should be capitalized.

Comment: hi, if i added this on my waterMain class, i would have to create the firebullet on the waterMain class, i am trying to make the bullet function called from my Gunner class.

Comment: y should u going to add in waterMain class, u can add in gunner class.